# How to sort value based on the value in 2nd column of a file using shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I wrote a shell script to get name,search_id and time .i want to sort the value base on search_id. i mean i want to short the 2nd column. i wrote the bellow script.

```
$LOGFILE | sort -k 2,2 > ssss.csv
```

but  `$LOGFILE | sort -k 2,2 > ssss.csv` sort the fist column and 2nd column. But I only want to sort the 2nd column

what i want is if i give this as my input file
my input

```
 aaa, 123, 12:23
 dsd, 123, 12.43
 sds, 234, 12.45
 sds, 345, 12.47
 sde, 233, 13.34
 dfg, 234, 13.45
 fgh, 236, 14.65
```

expected output

```
 aaa, 123, 12:23
 dsd, 123, 12.43
 sde, 233, 13.34
 sds, 234, 12.45
 dfg, 234, 13.45
 fgh, 236, 14.65
 sds, 345, 12.47
```

Can you help this. Many thanks

Comment: [edit key](https://twitter.com/H2CO3_iOS/status/385412992374153216), just because.

Comment: try `sort +1n` (assuming you want a numeric sort)

Comment: It doesn't sort the first column as you've mentioned, the third one actually affects the output you're observing.

Comment: Does you rinput file actually have spaces at the beginning of the line like what you've posted? If so, then you might want `-k3,3`...

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for the `-s` option to `sort`:

```
   -s, --stable
          stabilize sort by disabling last-resort comparison
```

For you example:

```
$ sort -s -k 2,2 inputfile
aaa 123 12:23
dsd 123 12.43
sde 233 13.34
sds 234 12.45
dfg 234 13.45
fgh 236 14.65
sds 345 12.47
```

Comment: @stacktome It seems that you're not using GNU sort.  I'd doubt that if your version of sort doesn't support the option, then you might need to resort to some other way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

`sort -k 2,2n`should work. I have testedit below.
n here means numerical sort.

```
> cat temp
aaa 123 12:23
dsd 123 12.43
sds 234 12.45
sds 345 12.47
sde 233 13.34
dfg 234 13.45
fgh 236 14.65
> sort -k 2,2n temp
aaa 123 12:23
dsd 123 12.43
sde 233 13.34
dfg 234 13.45
sds 234 12.45
fgh 236 14.65
sds 345 12.47
>
```